# Переадресация с http на https

Tags: php, .htaccess, https

Мой сервер поддерживает защищенное соединение, но по умолчанию работает на http. HTTPS используется только для админки. Если пользователь работает в админке (url='https://site.com/admin') и скопирует из url кусочек '[site.com/admin](http://site.com/admin)', затем вставит в новую вкладку и отправит запрос, то он отправится на сервер, там произойдет редирект на 'https://site.com/admin' (редирект делается средствами `php`, а не спомощью `.htaccess`). Скажите, пожалуйста, пока http запрос будет идти к серверу по адресу '[site.com/admin](http://site.com/admin)' и пока не произойдет редирект, он будет в незащищенном соединении? Злоумышленник теоретически сможет перехватить идентификатор сессии? Если использовать редирект с помощью .htaccess, это как-то меняет ситуацию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зависит от того, как вы устанавливаете сессионные куки. [Установка куки](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php)

Обратите внимание на параметр secure, он выставляет соответствующий флаг на куку, что заставляет браузер передавать такие куки только через https. При обращении по http он просто не пошлет их вам. А вы в свою очередь, не должны пытаться установить ему сессионную куку, не убедившись, что он пришел через https.

Если вы используете стандартные php сессии, то вот описание [session](http://php.net/manual/ru/session.security.php). `session.cookie_secure=On`

Comment: Благодарю, единственное, у меня не чистый php, а микрофреймворк silex, попробую найти, как там установить поведение cookie